# fs.watch calling method when not supposed to?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm rather new to node.js and javascript aswell, and I keep running into an error with the code below.

```
fs.watch('F:/junk', (eventType, filename) => {
    if(filename && filename.split('.')[1].match("zip")) {
        try {
            var zip = new azip(dir + filename);
        } catch(err) { return console.log(err); }
        try {
            zip.extractAllTo(dir + filename.split('.')[0], false);
        } catch(err) { return console.log(err); }
    }
});
```

and the error. the error only occurs after successfully running extractAllTo (adm-zip), and doesn't occur at all if I take that bit out.

```
if(filename && filename.split('.')[1].match("zip")) {
TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
```

I'm using the same file for testing every time, with the name dummyfile.zip

I can create another if statement within the first one and it'll work fine, but seems a bit redundant doing it that way

Comment: Might log `filename` ? Seems like it has no dot in it

Comment: I log the extension the using the same methods, I just removed it as I figured I might aswell remove irrelevant code - anyhow, it does have a dot in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must test for the existence of array element 2 (or index 1). There are numerous reasons. Without knowing operating system and file structure it is impossible to tell you. For instance, fs.watch() will return a directly - if the directory has no '.', then fail. This is the same if a file has no extension.

To validate this, in the console do this:

```
let str = "directory name";
str.split('.');
str.split('.')[1].match('test');
```

view the output.

**Consider**

```
if(filename && filename.includes('.zip')) {
      // work
   }
}
```

code is a little more verbose, but will avoid the error caused by directories and files that do not have extensions and files with leading dots, etc.

Comment: I changed my original post a bit, anyhow the dir variable is 'F:/junk', and the file I'm using to test every time is named dummyfile.zip - I already tried using another if statement within the first one, but surely it should be possible to do it without nesting if statements?

Comment: Just for giggles, try changing: `filename.split('.')[1].match("zip")' to   `filename.includes('.zip')` and see what happens

Comment: Check out this REPL.it and see if you can replicate the issue. This works fine for me. https://repl.it/@randycasburn/LuxuriousWhimsicalPrinter